# Mysql - Want to Join two tables without NULL Values

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain, why i can't get the attributes from my table , which is called *pep*.
Both tables are not empty.

```
SELECT * FROM pep 
RIGHT JOIN  zusammen ON zusammen._id_fk = pep.id
WHERE MATCH(zusammen.concat_Names) AGAINST(suche IN boolean mode)
LIMIT 50;
```

The last 5 columns are comming from the *zusammen* table

[image]

Comment: that 's what right join makes it takes all riows from the right tabke and join all froom the left, and when there is no matching row it adds NULL

Comment: But the first and the second table has values. So if i search for the value '10101078150.00' i got a hit in the first table (right one)

Comment: Try a inner join and a left join and see the results then if it doesn't match up you have some ids that are not in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `WHERE MATCH(zusammen.concat_Names) AGAINST(suche IN boolean mode) AND pep.id IS NOT NULL`

Check relevance score

```
SELECT
   WHERE MATCH(zusammen.concat_Names) AGAINST(suche IN boolean mode) as score,
   pep.*,
   zusammen.*
FROM pep 
RIGHT JOIN  zusammen ON zusammen._id_fk = pep.id
WHERE MATCH(zusammen.concat_Names) AGAINST(suche IN boolean mode)
LIMIT 50;
```